# What does the comma operator (expression, expression) means in Javascript when doing condition evaluation?

Tags: javascript

We minify our code with uglify-js and I have spotted a strange format which is used when compiling the following javascript:

```
console.debug(`[NotificationOpenedHandler] Received additionalData:`, data);
if(data.type && data.id) {
// more code...
```

This will be turned into the following:

```
if (console.debug(`[NotificationOpenedHandler] Received additionalData:`, e), e.type && e.id) {
```

First I thought its some compiler error, likely generated by uglify-js when trying to minimize the code but after testing it seems `(true, true & false)` it's a valid expression (No syntax error).

The value of the first expression doesn't matter so

```
(true, true & false) // -> false
(true, true & true) // -> true
(false, true & false) // -> false
(false, true & true) // -> true
```

My question, what does this expression mean?

Comment: [Logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) and [When is the comma operator useful?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9579546)

Comment: [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: return (x += 1, x); // the same as return ++x; process x = x +1 then return. comma operator in your case is processing before returning

Comment: Another possible dup-target: [Why does \[5,6,8,7\]\[1,2\] = 8 in Javascript](//stackoverflow.com/q/7421013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question, what does this expression mean?

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand (right most one).

Example:

```
if (y = f(x), y > x) {
    // do something ...
}
```

This executes first the `y = f(x)` which sets up a value for `y` (that depends on `x`). Then checks if `y > x`. If `True` then `do something`, otherwise do nothing. It is the same as:

```
y = f(x);
if (y > x) {
    // do something ...
}
```

In your examples:

```
(true, true & false)
// process `true` (does nothing)
// returns the result of `true & false` => false

(true, true & true)
// process `true` (does nothing)
// returns the result of `true & true` => true

(false, true & false)
// process `false` (does nothing)
// returns the result of `true & false` => false

(false, true & true)
// process `false` (does nothing)
// returns the result of `true & true` => true
```

Further examples:

```
(true, true, true, false) // returns false
(false, false, false, true) // returns true
```

So, in your application code:

```
if (console.debug(`[NotificationOpenedHandler] Received additionalData:`, e), e.type && e.id) {
```

Is the same as:

```
console.debug(`[NotificationOpenedHandler] Received additionalData:`, data);
if(data.type && data.id) {
```